Adaptive v-container size
I'm trying to make an adaptive v-container size so that it changes depending on the screen resolution.
I use the Composition API
<template>
    <v-container class="bg-surface-variant">
        <v-row class="mb-6" no-gutters>
            <v-col :cols="cols[0]">
                <v-sheet class="pa-2 ma-2">
                    .v-col-{{ cols[0] }}
                </v-sheet>
            </v-col>

            <v-col :cols="cols[1]">
                <v-sheet class="pa-2 ma-2">
                    .v-col-{{ cols[1] }}
                </v-sheet>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>

</template>

<script setup>

import { computed } from 'vue';
import { useDisplay } from 'vuetify';

const cols = computed(() => {
    const { lg, sm } = useDisplay();
    return lg ? [3, 9]
        : sm ? [9, 3]
            : [6, 6]
})

</script>

Unfortunately, this code doesn't work and I don't understand why(
I tried to rewrite this code using the Options API and everything worked, but for the project I need the Composition API.

Check the many examples shown in the documentation for useDisplay, the returned values are all refs, so you must use .value to access inner value.  Your current code is just checking truthiness of objects. What you really want is return lg.value ? [3, 9] : sm.value > [9, 3] : [6, 6]

lg and sm are refs !
That means lg will always be truthy, but lg.value could be either true or false.
Replace your computed with:
const cols = computed(() => {
    const { lg, sm } = useDisplay();
    return lg.value ? [3, 9]
        : sm.value ? [9, 3]
            : [6, 6]
})


Edit: after reading your comment, I realized the useDisplay is not at the right place, you have to call it only once, so take it out of the computed

const { lg, sm } = useDisplay();


const cols = computed(() => {
    return lg.value ? [3, 9]
        : sm.value ? [9, 3]
            : [6, 6]
})



Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. There is an error in the console:
Uncaught (in promise)
Error: [Vuetify] composables must be called from inside a setup function

Oh I see, I just edited my answer, please check it out!

Everything is working now, thanks!
